# CLion Cmake mysql.h missunderstanding

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11, cmake, clion

i'm new to c++ development.
   I want to try to use MySQL database, but can't understand whats wrong with it. Here is my code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <mysql.h>
    MYSQL *connection, mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    int query_state;

    int main() {
        mysql_init(&mysql);
        //connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"host","user",
        //                   "password","database",port,"unix_socket",clientflag);
        connection = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost",
                                        "root","qwer","cpp_data",3306,0,0);
        if (connection == NULL) {
            std::cout << mysql_error(&amp;mysql) << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        query_state = mysql_query(connection, "select user_count()");
        if (query_state !=0) {
            std::cout << mysql_error(connection) << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        result = mysql_store_result(connection);
        while (( row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL) {
            std::cout << "Number of active users : " << row[0] << std::endl;
        }

        mysql_free_result(result);
        mysql_close(connection);

        return 0;
    }
```

When i run my programm it says **C:\Users\user\CLionProjects\my-cpp-training\main.cpp:9:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory**

I will provide my CMakeList, there are some more sources which i wrote by learning. Here it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_cpp_training)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(D:/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.9-winx64/include)
include_directories ("D:/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.9-winx64/include")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp util/ContrainerUtils.cpp classes/Examples.cpp classes/Person.cpp classes/Person.h pointers/PointersArithmatic.cpp classes/Object.cpp classes/Object.h classes/Animal.cpp classes/Animal.h classes/Vector.cpp classes/Vector.h bussiness-layer/user.cpp util/Out.cpp util/Out.h classes/Container.cpp classes/Container.h classes/Vector_container.cpp classes/Vector_container.h util/PropertiesReader.cpp util/PropertiesReader.h util/Settings.cpp util/Settings.h)
add_executable(my_cpp_training ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries (my_cpp_training mysqlcppconn)
```

Here i will show that i have that library downloaded and extracted on my computer by path i using in CMakeList.txt

[path to mysql c++ library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewdAr.png)

Please help me, and not just like writing you thoughts, i allready googled half a day, and read a lot stuff. Just write here in this like you are not correct, or you forgot this code or line.

Comment: is mysql.h actually in the path you're specifying?

Comment: yeap, you can click on link "path to mysql c++ library" and you will see picture of this

Comment: right. so it's not actually on disk. You have downloaded the mysqlcppconn c++ connector, not the mysql C connector.

Comment: thanks a lot, i just understood thats it should be #include "mysql_connection.h"

Answer (score 0):

Richard Hodges was right. Here is his comment:

right. so it's not actually on disk. You have downloaded the mysqlcppconn c++ connector, not the mysql C connector.

So in my way i can use use mysql_connection.h or download right library.
Thanks a lot, Richard